# Hide li with empty span

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using materialize css. I want to hide all empty span which is inside an li tag. here is the screen shoot... I have gone through some post on how to hide empty li and div. Here is the structure

```
<ul id="select-options-c35dff64-99a4-b8cf-f4ed-079e4cffca0d" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown" style="width: 260px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none; opacity: 1;">
<li class=""><span> Select Parent Trade</span></li>
<li class=""><span> Civil &amp; Interior Works  </span></li>
<li class=""><span>   </span></li>
<li class=""><span>   </span></li>
<li class=""><span>   </span></li>
</ul>
```

The classes are automatically populated when a value is selected. I just want to hide those li with empty span.

I have tried

```
li span:empty {
    display: none;
}

$("li").each(function() {

    if(!$.trim($(this).html())) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

which does not work. i have tried targeting the `select-dropdown` class. 
Any advice or solution would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: For future reference `:empty` only applies if the element in question has no whitespace between tags (`<span></span>` - will work, `<span>   </span>` - will not work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost there...

Trim the text, and then check if its length is zero:

```js
$(function() {
  $('li').each(function() {
    if( $.trim( $(this).find('span').text() ).length == 0 ) {
      $(this).hide();
      
      console.log( 'li number ' + ($(this).index()+1) + ' is hidden' );
    }
  });
});
```

```css
li { border: 1px solid blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="select-options-c35dff64-99a4-b8cf-f4ed-079e4cffca0d" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown" style="width: 260px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;  opacity: 1;">
  <li class=""><span> Select Parent Trade</span></li>
  <li class=""><span> Civil &amp; Interior Works  </span></li>
  <li class=""><span>   </span></li>
  <li class=""><span>   </span></li>
  <li class=""><span>   </span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the `text` instead of `html`

```
$("li").each(function() {
    if($(this).text().trim().length) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

If there can other nodes than `span` then directly check the text of `span`

```
$("li").each(function() {
    if($(this).find( "span" ).text().trim().length) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't require jquery or trimming...

```js
var spans = document.querySelectorAll('span');

[].map.call(spans,function(n){
   !n.innerText && (n.parentElement.style.display = 'none');
})

// using ES6 can be even easier
for( n of [...spans] )
  !n.innerText && (n.parentElement.style.display = 'none');
```

```css
li { border: 1px solid blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="select-options-c35dff64-99a4-b8cf-f4ed-079e4cffca0d" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown" style="width: 260px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;  opacity: 1;">
  <li class=""><span> Select Parent Trade</span></li>
  <li class=""><span> Civil &amp; Interior Works  </span></li>
  <li class=""><span>   </span></li>
  <li class=""><span>   </span></li>
  <li class=""><span>   </span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`:empty` selector](https://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/)** in your condition like this:

```
$("li").each(function() {
  if ($(this).find("span:empty").length > 0) {
    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
$("li").each(function() {
  if ($(this).find("span:empty").length > 0) {
    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

```css
li {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="select-options-c35dff64-99a4-b8cf-f4ed-079e4cffca0d" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown" style="width: 260px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;  opacity: 1;">
  <li class=""><span> Select Parent Trade</span></li>
  <li class=""><span> Civil &amp; Interior Works  </span></li>
  <li class=""><span></span></li>
  <li class=""><span></span></li>
  <li class=""><span></span></li>
</ul>
```

**Note:**

Notice that the spaces in the `span` elements should be trimmed, otherwise `span:empty` won't match the span.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("li").each(function(index,key) {
  if($(this).find('span').text() == ""){
    $(key).hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="select-options-c35dff64-99a4-b8cf-f4ed-079e4cffca0d" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown" style="width: 260px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 1;">
<li class=""><span> Select Parent Trade</span></li>
<li class=""><span> Civil &amp; Interior Works  </span></li>
<li class=""><span></span></li>
<li class=""><span></span></li>
<li class=""><span></span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a situation like this, I need to be able to display: none; -webkit-flex:none; on an li that contains an empty a tag like in this example.

```
<ul class="social-menu">
 <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
 <li><a></a></li>
 <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

Im not sure Im seeing a solution I suppose but this seems like the most relevant post for it here. Any other thoughts on this example.